# Negative F-test value comparing two nested models

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, f-test

I am comparing two non-linear nested models - let me call them model A and model B. Model B has one parameter more than model A, i.e. model A can be obtained as a special case of model B. These two models are then used to fit the same set of empirical data. The reduced chi-squared $\chi^2_{\mathrm{red}}$ obtained from this fit are $\chi^2_{\mathrm{red, A}} \sim 0.531$ and $\chi^2_{\mathrm{red, B}} \sim 0.952$, and hence I would state that model B performs better than model A in describing these data.

Now, I would like to perform an F-test to measure how much the additional parameter (from A to B) has improved the fit. Referring to Eq.(11.50) of Bevington's Data Reduction and Error Analysis for the Physical Sciences, I would have the following formula to compute the F-ratio:

$F=\frac{\chi^2_A-\chi^2_B}{\chi^2_\mathrm{red,B}}$,

where $\chi^2_A$ and $\chi^2_B$ are the chi-squared of the two models, and $\chi^2_\mathrm{red,B}$ is the reduced chi-squared of model B. Here, I am testing the null hypothesis that the additional parameter does not improve the fit. Supposing that the dofs of model A are $\nu_A=17$ and the dofs of model B are $\nu_B=16$, then I would get:

$F=\frac{0.531 \ \cdot \ 17 - 0.952 \ \cdot \ 16}{0.952} \sim -6.517 $.

Hence, I have obtained a negative F-test value. How should I interpret this result? Did I use the correct formula? I.e. should I take the absolute value of the difference at the numerator or adopt a completely different expression to compute the F-test ratio?

Comment: Are you sure you have copied the right values of $\chi^2$ from your output? I would have expected model B to have a lower value than model A.

Comment: @mdewey I am sure of having copied the values correctly, the formula I've used for the chi-squared determination is $\chi^2 = \sum_{i=1}^{N} \ \frac{(y_i - f_i)^2}{\sigma_i^2}$, where $y_i$ are my data, $f_i$ the corresponding expected values and $\sigma_i$ the errors on the measures. Is there something wrong with this?

Comment: Setting aside penalties for extra parameters, which model performs better (in terms of square loss or whatever metric you're using)?

Comment: @Dave In terms of $\chi^2$ (calculated with the formula I provided above, i.e. not the reduced one) I get that model B corresponds to a higher value ($\chi^2_B \sim 15.2$) than model A ($\chi^2_A \sim 9$). I have also checked which model yields the highest mean square loss, i.e. $\frac{1}{N} \sum_{i=1}^{N} (y_i-f_i)^2$, and again model A yields a lower mean square loss than model B (38 vs. 48).